# Does any complete linear order of size $2^{\aleph_0}$ embed into $(\mathbb{R},<)$?

Tags: order-theory, model-theory

Can I embed every complete linear order $(A,<^A)$ with $\vert A\vert=2^{\aleph_0}$ into $(\mathbb{R},<)$. If not, what could be conditions on $(A,<^A)$ to make this work?

I know that any separable complete dense linear order without endpoints is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R},<)$. So similar as you prove that any countable linear order embeds into $(\mathbb{Q},<)$ by densifying it and using the isomorphism of the expansion and $(\mathbb{Q},<)$, I thought about densifying  $(A,<^A)$, but I am not sure of how to proceed, if possible.

Comment: Here "linear order" means "total order", right?

Comment: Yes, it does @Gae.S.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A well-ordered set embeds into $(\Bbb R,<)$ iff it is countable. Assuming ZFC, there is a well-ordered set of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$. This cannot be embedded into $(\Bbb R,<)$.

Comment: Note that there's also a choiceless version of this - namely, in ZF alone there is a surjection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\omega_1$ and the linear order $\omega_1+1$ is compact with the order topology but does not embed into $(\mathbb{R},<)$.

Comment: I thought so that completeness was too little to assume. Is there a known set of assumptions on $(A,<^A)$ such that this becomes possible?

Comment: You need some kind of separability hypothesis to ensure that $(A, <^A)$ embeds in $\mathbb{R}$.  You might find this summary interesting: https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/geschke/papers/SeparableLinearOrders2.pdf